# On input focus anchor tag click should be done in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input and anchor tag. Now I want to fire anchor click on input focus. How can I do this in React.js?

I used `window.history.pushState` but this is not working.

My code:

```js
const focusFun = (e) => {
    window.history.pushState("", "", "/page#myid");
}

<input 
type="text"
onFocus={(e) =>
focusFun(e, props.data)
}
>

<a href="#myid">this anchor should be clicked on input focus</a>
```

Comment: It's just `window.location = '#myid';` isn't it?

Comment: its not working....

Answer (score 0):

You just need to simulate the anchor tag click with the `element.click()` method.
So you need to do this:

```
const linkRef = useRef(null)

// then

<input 
type="text"
onFocus={() =>
   linkRef.current.click();
}
>

<a href="#myid" ref={linkRef}>this anchor should be clicked on input focus</a>
```

Or in your case, you can just scroll into the element with `element.scrollIntoView()`:

```
<input 
type="text"
onFocus={() =>
   document.querySelector("#myid").scrollIntoView();
}
>
```